# Android error "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread"

Tags: java, android, xml, adt

I am new programming with Android and I am having problems with a very simple example in ADT. I only have two ImageView in a FrameLayout each one, but when I test it with my phone the app goes really slow when it doesn't have any logic because I didn't touch the java folder.

This is the error I get in

```
12-16 16:17:43.261 18238-18238/com.example.brank.acocinapp I/Choreographer: Skipped 64 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-16 16:17:44.781 18238-18248/com.example.brank.acocinapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 26.044ms
12-16 16:17:44.831 18238-18238/com.example.brank.acocinapp W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000596046461
```

This is the xml of my content_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.brank.acocinapp.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/home2" />
    </FrameLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:src="@drawable/home1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

    </FrameLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I have to mention that if I comment one of the two FrameLayout the problem doesn't exists.

### Edit

I also put the two images in the folder Drawable (I don't know if this affect) but I saw in a tutorial that I have to put the images in the subfolder in Drawable (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi) the thing is that this subfolders doesn't exists so I paste my images in the Drawable.

Comment: Its possible that your images are very big? You can create a folder **drawable-nodpi** for put your images.

Comment: Using AsyncTasks and Threads would help. If the needed drawable folders don't exist yet, just make them.

Comment: @JoseAngelManeiro My images are 1024x768 png and the size is 1.40M, do you think it is a big image for an app? What should be the recommend resolution and size?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein if I create those folders and I put the images there, I got an error in the line  android:src="@drawable/home1" in the xml

Comment: But this is really what you have to do: create them if missing. 1024x768 will occupy 1024 * 768 * 4 = 3145728 bytes in memory. 4 is R, G, B and A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok what might be happening is that the OS is trying to do a lot of processing on your images, which you may have chosen of a high resolution. What you can do is try to create multiple resolution of your image (mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi). you can take the standard size of the image as mdpi and increase their sizes in the ratio of 1.5,2,3 respectively for hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi. when you have these images put them in the drawable folders if you don't have them create them by yourself. Sometimes this may even cause OOM's in android. one article [explaining](http://huteri.me/2015/07/11/beware-of-setting-image-resources-for-preview-purpose-in-xml/) it.

Comment: Yeah I saw something about hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi the thing is that those folders don´t exist. Should I create those folders in the folder "Drawable"?

Comment: yes create folders like drawable-mdpi,drawable-hdpi,drawable-xhdpi,drawable-xxhdpi

Comment: Now I get the next error: "Couldn´t resolve resource @drawable/home2" I put the image in drawable-mdpi

Comment: do you also have the image with different resolutions in other folders ??

Comment: Ok, thanks man the problem is solved, I put the different resolution images in other folders and moved the drawable-hdpi (and others) to res/ so, I had to create the folders you told me in res/ and no res/drawable/, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the documentation for `AsyncTask`and `Thread`
There is also a very explanatory guide for [Main Threads and Worker Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

What is happening is that you perform a lot of cpu-consuming processes in the main thread which may cause your main UI thread to hang. A solution to this is to do the whole image processing in a worker thread and to keep the main thread only for the UI interaction.

Comment: Ok , I  toke a look and it could be a solution making a thread for the image processing but how can I do this? The thing I did for test it is create a thread that do the next sentence: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); in the method OnCreate() in the MainActivity, but when I test it in my phone it throws force close. What is the sentence that make the images processing?

Comment: The worker thread should not touch the main UI , so you cannot setContentView in the worker thread. The implementation of AsyncTask is to override doInBackground() method ,in which you will put all the image processing procedure and override the onPostExecute() method  which you will use to update the main UI thread